# ¿Como calcular un RSI sin "for"?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando calcular un RSI, pero en cierto momento, me veo obligado a utilizar un "for", procedimiento que va a demorar mucho (y que por lo demás, tampoco me funciona). Es posible hacerlo utilizando otras herramientas de python? Creo que con un iloc ix o loc podría pero no logro figurarlo.

Mi código es:

```
        rent_diaria = df[var]/df[var].shift(1) - 1 
        gains = rent_diaria.copy()
        gains[gains<0]=0
        avg_gain_a = gains.rolling(window).mean()
        avg_gain = pd.DataFrame(avg_gain_a.copy())
        for x in avg_gain:
            avg_gain[x] = (avg_gain[x-1]*13 + gains[x])/14      # <-- aqui falla.

        losses = rent_diaria.copy()
        losses[losses>0]=0
        avg_losses_a = losses.rolling(window).mean()
        avg_losses = pd.DataFrame(avg_losses_a.copy())
        for x in avg_losses:
            avg_losses[x] = (avg_losses[x-1]*13 + losses[x])/14

        rs = avg_gains/avg_losses
        rsi = 100 - (100/(1+rs))
```

Es necesario hacerlo utilizando esta metodología. En otras preguntas he visto que lo construyen simplemente dividiendo MAs de gains en losses, pero no es el caso que busco.
El desafío está en hacer que el primer RSI (t=0) sea la división de avg_gain(t=0) en avg_losses(t=0) y que desde allí los siguientes avg_gain y avg_losses se construyan a partir del avg_gain y avg_losses anterior. Es decir:

```
# avg_gain (t=1) = (avg_gain(t=0)*13 + gain(t=1))/14
```

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar una muestra de los datos que usas y la salida que esperas, así podrían ayudarte más facilmente con tu problema.

Comment: Hola, claro. Una tabla exactamente como la que se muestra en este articulo. Se puede descargar un excel allí mismo para ver las formulas. Saludos
https://school.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=technical_indicators:relative_strength_index_rsi